# How to store and retrieve AWS Cognito JWT Token in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, amazon-cognito

My Android app authenticates with Cognito in an `AsyncTask` and receives the JWT token as part of the `CognitoUserSession`. This is then set in the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` using `setLogins()`.

I would like to retrieve this JWT token in another `AsyncTask`. However `getLogins()` on the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` is returning a size 0 Map.

What is the easiest way to get back the token? Should I store it in Shared Preferences again?

Answer (score 1):

Get/SetLogins in the SDK just update a map inside the credentials provider, they don't save it long term. If you need to access it across threads at some arbitrary time, that would be a reasonable way to accomplish it. Otherwise, just use the exact same credentials provider and it'll be there.

Answer (score 0):

`CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` is actually using the shared preferences to save data, but `getLogins` is returning a size 0 hash.

The easy way to persist data (JWT) was the shared preferences in the `AsyncTask` `doInBackgraound` method and retrieve wherever it is required.

Comment: Correct. It uses shared preferences to save creds/identity id...etc., however it does not store the token on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Could get these token(refresh token / access token / id token) from aws in login time and put in preference like following:

```
 final AuthenticationHandler authenticationCallBackManager = new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) {
            /*SharedPreferenceCacheManager.writeString(
                    LoginActivity.this,
                    "ACCESS_TOKEN",
                    userSession.getAccessToken().getJWTToken());*/
            //System.out.println(userSession.getAccessToken().getJWTToken());//<<-------access token

            /*SharedPreferenceCacheManager.writeString(
                    LoginActivity.this,
                    "REFRESH_TOKEN",
                    userSession.getRefreshToken().getToken());*/
            //System.out.println(userSession.getRefreshToken().getToken());//<<---------refresh token

            SharedPreferenceCacheManager.writeString(
                    LoginActivity.this,
                    "ID_TOKEN",
                    userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
            //System.out.println(userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());//<<-----------id token(this id uses Authorization in aws-side)

            //....
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(
                    userId,
                    String.valueOf(editTextPassword.getText()), null);

            //System.out.println(CognitoServiceConstants.AUTH_PARAM_USERNAME);
            //System.out.println(CognitoServiceConstants.AUTH_PARAM_REFRESH_TOKEN);

            // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);

            // Allow the sign-in to continue
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
           //....
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
           //....
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
           //....
        }
    };
```